# ProxyError only on post requests, not on get

Tags: python, python-2.7, https, python-requests

```
import requests

s = requests.session()
s.proxies = {'https': 'https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8888'}
s.get("https://www.tumblr.com/")
s.post("https://www.tumblr.com/")
```

GET will work fine, but POST will throw a ProxyError. Any ideas why?

> ProxyError: Cannot connect to proxy. Socket error: Tunnel connection
>   failed: 400 Bad Request.

Comment: Try using `s.proxies = {'https': 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8888'}` instead. We have abysmal support for HTTPS proxies

Comment: Same error. I was tinkering with that before.

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: Which minor version of 2.7 (e.g., 2.7.8)?

Comment: Python 2.7.5 on local machine

Comment: It seems like the proxy doesn't like the `CONNECT` request, can you provide a tcpdump?

Comment: Do you get this error even you do POST request first, or multiple consecutive POST requests on same session?

Comment: I commented out the `get` and then the `post` worked. Then I added a 5 second sleep between the 2 requests, and it still gave `400 Bad Request` on the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible reason is proxy server incorrectly resets connection or Session connection pool cant understand that it closed.
If you don't need connection pooling you can use

```
import requests

proxies = {'https': 'https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8888'}
requests.get("https://www.tumblr.com/", proxies=proxies)
requests.post("https://www.tumblr.com/", proxies=proxies)
```

**UPDATE**. It's related to this [issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1805) and apparently will be fixed in upcoming release > 2.3.0. Currently master branch of requests also works fine.

Comment: This works. Any other possible reasons why the session didn't work?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no other reason, as requests.post and get methods creating Session object instance and make one request and then it Session is deleted. Your problem will be present for multiple consecutive requests through proxy request in one session get or post.